# How is it possible to use Android libraries in libGDX?

Tags: android, libgdx

I want to make an android application game that uses both android API like Location, even Google Maps API and also use libGDX framework as well. How is this possible?

I noticed there's an Android and a core folder created when making a libGDX project, where do all the classes go, but I'm very confused.

Answer (score 3):

Anything **Android** specific should be in your *-android* project and anything general goes in the *-core* project.

Normally you'd have an interface in the *-core* project that is implemented by classes in your *-android*, *-desktop* or web project and in your platform specific launcher (for example in AndroidLauncher.java) you'd inject the platform specific implementation of the interface.

Comment: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code

Answer (score 0):

> Android specific libraries may be added to the `android` module **only** in `build.gradle` for the overall project.

If your `core` module relies on **android specific modules**, you will need to use a **different solution** for the other modules.

Thus, if you want to use Google Maps API on both Android & Desktop, you will need to utilize a different library for your `desktop` module.